# The field generated by the empirical distribution function

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

**The Gist**

I've got three question related to the field generated by the empirical distribution function ("the empirical field").

1. Is the empirical field identical to the symmetric field?
2. Are all functions that are invariant under permutation of their argument measurable w.r.t. the empirical field?
3. If $f\left(x,y\right)$ is measurable w.r.t. the product field $\Omega^n\otimes\mathcal{A}$ and for each $y$, $f\left(\cdot,y\right)$ is measurable w.r.t. the empirical field, is $f$ measurable w.r.t. the product of the empirical field and $A$?

**In Detail**

Following is a more complete and precise statement of these questions.

Let $\left(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1\right)$, $\left(\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_2\right)$ be measurable spaces (if it helps, they may be assumed to be Borel spaces). Denote by $\mathcal{P}$ the set of probability measures on $\left(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1\right)$ and by $\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{P}$ the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{P}$ generated by the sets of the form $\left\{P\in\mathcal{P}\space\mid:\space P(B)\leq t\right\}$, for all $B\in\mathcal{A}_1$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer. The empirical distribution function of order $n$ on $\left(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1\right)$ is the function

$$q:\Omega_1^n\rightarrow\mathcal{P},\space\space q\left(\left(x_1,\dots,x_n\right)\right)(B):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{1}_B\left(x_i\right)$$

It can be readily verified that $q$ is $\mathcal{A}_1^n/\mathcal{A}_\mathcal{P}$-measurable. The $\sigma$-algebra induced on $\mathcal{A}_1^n$ by $q$ will be denoted $\mathcal{A}_q$.

**Question #1**

For every $x\in\Omega_1^n$, $\Pi(x)$ will denote the set consisting of all $n!$ permutations of $x$. The symmetric field of order $n$ on $\left(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1\right)$ is the set

$$\mathcal{A}_\mathrm{sym}:=\left\{B\in\mathcal{A}_1^n\space\mid:\space\forall x\in B,\space\Pi(x)\subseteq B\right\}$$

It can be readily verified that $\mathcal{A}_\mathrm{sym}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. It is also clear that $\mathcal{A}_q\subseteq\mathcal{A}_\mathrm{sym}$.

My first question is: Is it the case that $\mathcal{A}_\mathrm{sym}\subseteq\mathcal{A}_q$?

**Question #2**

Denote by $F$ the set of real-valued, measurable functions over $\Omega_1^n$ that are invariant under permutation of their argument. Formally,

$$F:=\left\{f:\left(\Omega_1^n,\mathcal{A}_1^n\right)\rightarrow\left(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}\right)\space\mid:\space\forall x\in\Omega_1^n\forall y\in\Pi(x),\space f(x)=f(y)\right\}$$

It is clear that all $f\in F$ are $\mathcal{A}_\mathrm{sym}/\mathfrak{B}$-measurable.

My second question is: Is it the case that all $f\in F$ are $\mathcal{A}_q/\mathfrak{B}$-measurable? Obviously, if the answer to question #1 is affirmative, so is the answer to this question.

**Question #3**

Finally let $f:\Omega_1^n\times\Omega_2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $\mathcal{A}_1^n\otimes\mathcal{A}_2/\mathfrak{B}$-measurable and such that $f\left(\cdot,y\right)\in F$ for any fixed $y\in\Omega_2$.

My third question is: Is it the case that $f$ is $\mathcal{A}_q\otimes\mathcal{A}_2/\mathcal{B}$-measurable? Is it $\mathcal{A}_\mathrm{sym}\otimes\mathcal{A}_2/\mathcal{B}$-measurable?

**Motivation**

These questions - and particularly the last one - arose while reading Schervish's first chapter on exchangeable sequences of random variables. Specifically, he states the following proposition without proof (p. 42) with the reassurance that "it is easy to prove":

**Proposition 1.75.** Suppose that $X=\left(X_1,\dots,X_N\right)$ are exchangeable, that $k+n\leq N$, and that $j_1,\dots,j_n\in\left\{k+1,\dots,N\right\}$ are distinct. The conditional distribution of $X_{j_1},\dots,X_{j_n}$ given $\left(X_1,\dots,X_k\right)=\left(x_1,\dots,x_k\right)$ and $\mathbf{P}_N=P$ [$\mathbf{P}_N$ is Schervish's notation for the composition of the empirical distribution of order $N$ on $X$. - Evan Aad] is that of a simple random sample of size $n$ without replacement from the distribution $P$ with one ball for each of $x_1,\dots,x_k$ removed first.

In trying to prove this proposition, i started by denoting with $f\left(\left(x=\left(x_1,\dots,x_k\right),P\right),B\right)$ the function defined in the last sentence, namely $f\left(\left(x,P\right),B\right)$ is the probability that a simple random sample of size $n$ without replacement from the distribution $P$ with one ball for each of $x_1,\dots,x_k$ removed first will attain values in the Borel set $B$.

The first task i undertook was to show that for each $B$, $f\left(\cdot,B\right)$ was measurable. However, finding it difficult to show this when working directly with $P$, i attempted to reduce $f$ to the function $f'\left(\left(x,x'=\left(x_1,\dots,x_N\right)\right),B\right):=f\left(\left(x,q\left(x'\right)\right),B\right)$. I was able to define $f'$ in such a way (see below) that $f'\left(\cdot,B\right)$ was measurable w.r.t. the joint distribution of $\left(\left(X_1,\dots,X_k\right),\left(X_1,\dots,X_N\right)\right)$ and such that, given $x=\left(x_1,\dots,x_k\right)$, $f'\left(\left(x,\cdot\right),B\right)$ was invariant under permutation of $\left(x_1,\dots,x_N\right)$. But does this mean $f'$ is measurable with respect to the distribution of $\left(\left(X_1,\dots,X_k\right),\mathbf{P}_N\right)$? An affirmative answer to question 3 would be an affirmative answer to this question.

For completeness, here's how i defined $f'$.

First a simple notational convention: if $y=\left(x_1,\dots,x_N\right)$ and $\alpha$ is some sequence of indices $\in\left\{1,\dots,N\right\}$ of length $m$, then define $y_\alpha:=\left(y_{\alpha_1},\dots,y_{\alpha_m}\right)$.

Now, given $x=\left(x_1,\dots,x_k\right)$, $x'=\left(x_1,\dots,x_N\right)$, $B$, set $g\left(x,x'\right):=\sum_{y\in\Pi\left(x'\right)}\mathbb{1}_{\left\{x\right\}}(y_{\left(1,\dots,k\right)})$, define for all $0<g\left(x,x'\right)$,

$$
f'\left(\left(x,x'\right),B\right):=\frac{1}{g\left(x,x'\right)}\sum_{y\in\Pi\left(x'\right)}\mathbb{1}_{\left\{x\right\}}(y_{\left(1,\dots,k\right)})\frac{1}{n!{N\choose n}}\sum_{\alpha:\left\{1,\dots,n\right\}\overset{1:1}{\rightarrow}\left\{k+1,\dots,N\right\}}\mathbb{1}_B\left(y_\alpha\right)
$$

**References**

Schervish, Mark J. Theory of Statistics. 1995 (1st printing)